# -1, Basic Algebra and Integrals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have something like:

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $\displaystyle \int x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{x^3}{3}$

How do I correctly substitute the values into the function:

Is it: $((-1)^3) /3$ or $(-1^3)/3$.

I am a bit unsure. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, $\frac {1^3}3 - (\frac{-1^3}3) = \frac{1^3}{3} - \frac{(-1)^3}3$.

Comment: The notation $-1^3$ seems ambiguous, no?

Comment: Well it doesn't change anything because $-1^3 = -1$ and $(-1)^3=-1$.

Comment: Oh and by the way if you're looking for a tutorial on math formatting, it's [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to insert $x=-1$ into the formula $\dfrac{x^3}{3}$. To do that, just replace the $x$ by its value:
$$ \frac{x^3}{3} = \frac{(x)^3}{3} = \frac{(-1)^3}{3}. $$
Your second option $\frac{-1^3}{3}$ is incorrect because only the $1$ gets cubed, and not the $-$, but both are part of $x=-1$ and the formula tells you to cube the whole $x$.

Then the solution to the integral would be:
$$ \int_{-1}^1x^2dx = \left[ \frac{x^3}{3} \right]_{-1}^1 = \frac{1^3}{3} - \frac{(-1)^3}{3}. $$
Can you simplify it from here?

Comment: No, you want to insert $b=1$ into $\frac{x^3}{3}$ evaluate, and then subtract the evaluation at  $a = -1$ into $\frac{x^3}{3}$.

Comment: @amWhy Read my whole answer. Also, I don't think that the question is asking how to evaluate definite integrals, but rather how to substitute the value for $x$ into the expression correctly.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you meant, but I did read the question as I answered it in comments.

Comment: @amWhy Yeah, it's not totally clear what OP wants, so I think it is good to have both approaches as an answer.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you. That explains it completely. I knew (-1)^3 and -1^3 were different and couldn't remember which was correct. Thank you.

Comment: @MEcho Glad it helped. You can accept an answer using the little checkmark at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Like that :

$$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \left[\dfrac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-1}^1 = \dfrac{1^3}{3} - \dfrac{(-1)^3}{3} = \dfrac{2}{3}$$

If $F(x) = \dfrac{x^3}{3}$ then $F(-1) = \dfrac{(-1)^3}{3}$